# Move item in array to last position

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects. I want to move a selected object to the last position in the array. How do I do this in javascript or jquery?

Here is some code I have:

```
var sortedProductRow = this.product_row;

for (var s in sortedProductRow) {
    if (sortedProductRow[s]["parent_product_type"] != "")
        // Move this object to last position in the array
}
```

I'm looping through this with a for loop, and I want the output to be ordered so that all objects that does not have a "parent_product_type" value comes first, then those with a value.

Comment: An **object** is not an **array** and position is meaninglessness, it's only keys and values. read more - http://stackoverflow.com/q/5525795/104380

Comment: who says `sortedProductRow` is an object? you can iterate an array with for in as well (I don't say it's a good idea, but it's possible)

Comment: Hmm ok, then I'm not sure what I need to do. I can loop through this array with a for loop, and the objects come out in the order that they appear within the "array" (or object). So what do I need to do if I want to change the order that they come out of the for loop?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

to move an element (of which you know the index) to the end of an array, do this:

```
array.push(array.splice(index, 1)[0]);
```

If you don't have the index, and only the element, then do this:

```
array.push(array.splice(array.indexOf(element), 1)[0]);
```

Example:

```js
    var arr = [1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5];
    arr.push(arr.splice(arr.indexOf(6), 1)[0]);
    console.log(arr); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

> NOTE:
>
> this only works with Arrays (created with the `[ ... ]` syntax or
>   `Array()`) not with Objects (created with the `{ ... }` syntax or
>   `Object()`)

Comment: needs some more explanation. Although this solves the problem, no one is learning anything.

Comment: hi @Ferdi265 could you please explain why u have added [0] after array.splice method. Thanks in advance

Comment: `Array.splice()` returns an array containing all of the removed elements, so in this case, `[6]`. We only want to push `6` to the end of the array, so we take the first element of that array.

If you don't add the `[0]`, you will get `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6]]` instead

Comment: So to move an element to a specific index, we do:
`arr.splice(index, 0, arr.splice(arr.indexOf(6), 1)[0]);`

Comment: Maybe we can also do something like:

`Array.prototype.move = function(element, index) {
  arr.splice(index, 0, arr.splice(arr.indexOf(element), 1)[0]);
}`

Comment: @HDKT In 2020 and beyond? No. You need a *really* good reason to touch `Array.prototype`.

Answer (score 20):

Moving **the first element** of an array **to the end** of the same array

```js
    var a = [5,1,2,3,4];
    a.push(a.shift());
    console.log(a); // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

or this way

```js
    var a = [5,1,2,3,4];
    var b = a.shift();
    a[a.length] = b;
    console.log(a); // [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Moving **any element** of an array **to any position** in the same array

```js
    // move element '5' (index = 2) to the end (index = 4)
    var a = [1, 2, 5, 4, 3];
    a.splice(4,0,a.splice(2,1)[0]);
    console.log(a); // [1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
```

or it could be converted to a prototype as well, like this where `x` represents the current position of element while `y` represents the new position in array

```js
var a = [1, 2, 5, 4, 3];
Array.prototype.move = function(x, y){
      this.splice(y, 0, this.splice(x, 1)[0]);
      return this;
    };
    
    a.move(2,4);
    console.log(a); // ["1", "2", "4", "3", "5"]
```

**Answer to the @jkalandarov comment**

```
function moveToTheEnd(arr, word){
  arr.map((elem, index) => {
    if(elem.toLowerCase() === word.toLowerCase()){
      arr.splice(index, 1);
      arr.push(elem);
    }
  })
  return arr;
}
console.log(moveToTheEnd(["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango", "Lemon"],"Orange"));
```

Comment: Elegant solution, but this can only move the first element of the array to the end.

Comment: @Ferdi265 I don't know why I was sure that the OP wants to move the first element :)

Comment: Thanks but it's not the first element I want to move. I'm looping through the sortedProductRow array/object(?) and when I find a property name "parent_product_type" that has a value, I want to move it to the last position in the array. This way, my array will have only objects without a value for the property "parent_product_type" coming first, then all objects with a value for this property.

Comment: @JohanDahl Sorry :) I updated the answer to something more useful :) so give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I ended up using Ferdi's second method which worked well.

Comment: What if I want to move the elements that repeat several times in an array to the end of the array? Lets say, I want to move all 'b's to the end of an array?

Comment: For those who want to return the element that's being moved to the end of the array: `const output = a[a.push(a.shift())-1];`

Answer (score 11):

Immutable way:

```
const changedArr = [...prevArr.filter(a => a !== element), element]
```

Answer (score 9):

This is more clean, without using the array index of [0]

```
const colors = ['white', 'black', 'red', 'blue', 'green'];

// will push the blue to the end of the array
colors.push(colors.splice(colors.indexOf('blue'), 1).pop());

console.debug(colors);
// ["white", "black", "red", "green", "blue"]
```

Answer (score 5):

Using an anonymous function you can pass in the array and the value to filter by.

```
let concatToEnd = function (arr, val) {
        return arr.filter(function(x) {
            return x !== val; // filter items not equal to value
        }).concat(arr.filter(function(x) { // concatonate to filtered array
            return x === val; // filter items equal to value 
        })
    );
}

// invoke
concatToEnd(array, 'parent_product_type');
```

You could probably shorten this further:

```
let concatToEnd = (arr,val) => arr.filter(x => x !== val).concat(arr.filter(x => x === val))
```

This function filters the items which *do not equal* the value passed in, then concatenates the result (to the end of the filtered array) of *another* `filter` function which filters out the items which *do equal* the value you've passed in.

**This function essentially separates the array into 2 filtered parts and then concatenates them back together**

This hasn't been tested for your use-case, but I've used something similar to move all numbers of an array to the end of the index.

Answer (score 1):

Move any element to last position - for ***lodash*** users:

```
    const array = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] // output: A, B, C, D

// finds index of value 'B' and removes it
    _.pull(array , 'B') // output: A, C, D

// adds value of 'B' to last position
    _.concat(array , 'B') // output: A, C, D, B
```

Answer (score 1):

Moving all items equal so something to the end can also be done by concat.

```js
const myArray = [1, 0, 3, 5, 0, 'a', 3, 's']
    
const moveZerosToEnd = (arr) => {
   return arr.filter(item => item !== 0).concat(arr.filter(item => item === 0))
}

console.log(myArray)                 // [1, 0, 3, 5, 0, 'a', 3, 's']
console.log(moveZerosToEnd(myArray)) // [1, 3, 5, 'a', 3, 's', 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move any number of items by [splicing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) them, then [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) them into a [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).

```
const numberOfItems = 3;
let items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
items.push(...items.splice(0, itemsToMove))
```